# C# if labels 1-20

Tags: c#

Hey guys I got code like this.

```
if (finish.Bounds.IntersectsWith(move.Bounds))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Gratz you won!");
}
```

And I got bunch of other Labels about 10 that I need to do a pop up saying they failed. Is there a method of doing it without using about 20 if's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on how the labels are grouped, you probably most easily create an array and loop over it:

```
Control[] labels = new Control[] { label1, label2 };

foreach (Control c in labels)
{
    // use c
}
```

You could also loop over all controls and filter out those you want, but that might be more error prone than the above simple solution.

Comment: Thanks mate! Worked perfectly!